# How to select rows in pandas where variable number of columns match?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, match

So I have a pandas dataframe where the number of columns is variable. I want to keep only the rows where a subset of those columns match.

An example:

```
Name, Surname, Class1, Class2, Class3
John  Smith       1       1      -1   
Ned   Walker     -1      -1      -1
Walter White      1       1       1
```

From this dataframe I would like only to leave the rows where Class1, Class2 and Class3 match, so the output would be:

```
Name, Surname, Class1, Class2, Class3
Ned   Walker     -1      -1      -1
Walter White      1       1       1
```

However, sometimes the number of 'Class' columns vary from 1 to 4, so I could get a dataframe like this:

```
Name, Surname, Class1, Class2
John  Smith       1       1
Ned   Walker     -1      -1
Walter White      1       1
```

Where I would like only Class1 and Class2 to match. Or this:

```
Name, Surname, Class1, Class2, Class3, Class4
John  Smith       1       1      -1      1
Ned   Walker     -1      -1      -1      1
Walter White      1       1       1      1
```

Where all classes from 1 to 4 would need to have same value. What would be an efficient way to do it?

Comment: Take a look into this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero's answer with `.nunique(axis=1).eq(1)` is clearly the most pandas-y way of doing it, but for future reference this also works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(seed=42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(10,3)))
print(df)
print('\n')
print(df.loc[np.all([df[col] == df.iloc[:,0] for col in df],axis=0)])
```

which might be useful if you ever find yourself needing to check e.g. for specific values (just replace the `df.iloc[:,0]` by whatever value you'd like) or other logical conditions.

Comment: Thank you! Both answers were very helpful and both of these methods work, however your code seems to run much faster than Zero's which is very important in my case :)

Comment: Is that independent of the pre-filtering (to throw out everything not called `Class*`) that was necessary in @Zero 's code? I am actually somewhat surprised.

Answer (score 4):

Use `filter` and `nunique`

```
In [808]: df[df.filter(like='Class').nunique(1).eq(1)]
Out[808]:
     Name Surname  Class1  Class2  Class3  Class4
2  Walter   White       1       1       1       1
```

---

Details

```
In [809]: df
Out[809]:
     Name Surname  Class1  Class2  Class3  Class4
0    John   Smith       1       1      -1       1
1     Ned  Walker      -1      -1      -1       1
2  Walter   White       1       1       1       1

In [810]: df.filter(like='Class')
Out[810]:
   Class1  Class2  Class3  Class4
0       1       1      -1       1
1      -1      -1      -1       1
2       1       1       1       1

In [811]: df.filter(like='Class').nunique(1)
Out[811]:
0    2
1    2
2    1
dtype: int64

In [812]: df.filter(like='Class').nunique(1).eq(1)
Out[812]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```